# What is the significance of limit points?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, motivation

When I had my first taste of topology a couple of years ago, our lecturer emphasized the following notions.

- closed set, closure, closure point
- open set, interior, interior point

Of course, these are all basically different ways of talking about the same thing. For example, from the family of closed sets of a space we can obtain its closure operator, and the fixed points of the closure operator are precisely the closed sets; the open sets are precisely the complements of the closed sets, etc.

Anyway, the concepts were well-motivated from the viewpoint of continuous functions between metric spaces. For example, it was demonstrated that if $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function, then the following are equivalent

1. $f$ is continuous in the sense of $\epsilon$-$\delta$.
2. The preimage of a closed set under $f$ is closed.
3. The preimage of an open set under $f$ is open.
4. $f(\mathrm{cl} \,A)\subseteq\mathrm{cl}(f(A))$ for all $A \subseteq X$.
5. $\mathrm{cl}(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq f^{-1}(\mathrm{cl} \,B)$ for all $B \subseteq X$.
6. $f^{-1}( \mathrm{int} (B)) \subseteq \mathrm{int} ( f^{-1} ( B ) )$ for all $B \subseteq Y$.

etc.

Anyway, on Wikipedia there's some related concept that weren't really dealt with in the course I took, namely [limit points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) and [isolated points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point). I understand the definitions (Wikipedia is clear enough), yet at the same time I don't understand their significance. They just seem like closure points, but less well-behaved.

For example, the set of all closure points of a set always includes the original set. The same is true of the set of all limit points, so long as the original set did not possess any isolated points, indeed we get the same answer. The only time we get a different answer is when the original set has at least one isolated point; but, in this case, the act of taking the set of all limit points is no longer so well-behaved; indeed, it will never include the original set.

So, its not clear to me the benefit of thinking in terms of limit points, as opposed to closure points. In what circumstances are limit points the right concept, and, more broadly, what is their significance?

Comment: Well. First of all, "closure point" (or [adherent point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adherent_point)) is not a particularly useful notion. It just means "point in the closure". It seems like a waste of mental space to me to have a separate definition just for that.

Comment: @kahen: It is not useful but it may make your mental space more complete and orthogonal so it may in the end take “less space” because of “structural compression”.

Comment: @kahen, I don't think its really a big deal. Rather than saying $x$ is an element of the interior of $A$, we can say $x$ is an interior point of $A$. Likewise for the closure. Sure, its conceptually redundant, but linguistically I think its helpful.

Comment: I guess that it is a terminology coming from analysis, where a "limit point" is a point that can be reached with a convergent sequence, while an "isolated point" is a point that cannot be reached that way. I agree that they are not such a fundamental tool for general topology as the closure operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, like you, I wouldn't assign limit points quite the same conceptual status as say the closure operator or interior operator. But, it is indeed possible to define topologies using "limit point" as a primitive axiomatic notion.

The key word is "[derived set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29#Topology_in_terms_of_derived_sets)", which is actually an important notion. Given a subset $S$ of a topological space, the derived set $S'$ is the set of limit points of $S$. The key properties can be axiomatized: a (Cantor-Bendixson) *derivative* on a set $X$ is a monotone operator $\delta: P(X) \to P(X)$ that preserves finite unions (including the empty union $\emptyset$) such that $\delta^2(S) \subseteq \delta(S)$ and $a \in \delta(S)$ implies $a \in \delta(S \backslash \{a\})$, for every $S \in P(X)$.

Then, given a derivative on a set $X$, define $S \in P(X)$ to be $\delta$-closed if $\delta(S) \subseteq S$. It may be shown this gives the closed sets of a topology, such that $\delta(S)$ is the derived set of $S$ with respect to this topology. In this way, there is a natural bijection between topologies and Cantor-Bendixson derivatives, so that the two notions are essentially equivalent.

One reason not to fully accord derivatives the same fundamental status as (say) closure operators is that closure operators are far easier to work with in the setting of constructive mathematics (constructive topology), where for various reasons one might be interested in dropping the principle of excluded middle.

That said, derived sets are very important. It was Cantor's study of iterated derived sets in the real line that led him to his theory of ordinals and cardinals. Not that I am expert, but they are used a great deal in descriptive set theory.

**Edit:** Maybe the following will provide more of a "kick" for the OP.

**Problem:** Show that every infinite closed subset of the real line has cardinality either $\aleph_0$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$. Thus, the continuum hypothesis holds at least for *closed* subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

I won't spell out the answer in detail here -- I'd really recommend trying to think for oneself how to prove it -- but suffice it to say that a critical notion in the standard solution is that of "perfect set": a subspace $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (or more generally, of any separable metric space) is *perfect* if every point of $S$ is a limit point of $S$.

If you try this problem and get stuck, then try googling "Cantor-Bendixson theorem", and then see e.g. [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jsr25/Spring_11/Lecture_Notes/dst_lecture_notes_2011_lec_1.pdf) for a nice theorem (theorem 1.1) that concerns the cardinality of perfect sets.

The point is that it is limit point -- not closure point -- that is the "right" or appropriate concept for tackling this problem. Another problem along similar lines: show that a compact Hausdorff group is either finite or has cardinality at least $2^{\aleph_0}$. Again, it is the bifurcation of closure point into the separate notions of isolation point and limit point which is crucial to the analysis.

Comment: I mean, its cool and all that we can axiomatize the Cantor-Bendixson derivative function, and thank you for bringing the terminology "derived set" to my attention, but I still don't know why we would even bother *defining* the $\delta$ function, let alone axiomatizing it. I do like new perspectives, but they ought to have some sort of a *kick* or *benefit*, and I'm still looking for a benefit.

Comment: I have added something to my answer which might be more satisfying to you. (Your first two paragraphs had suggested to me that you were in search of a different kind of answer.) Did you try searching on the key words I provided in my earlier answer? :-)

Comment: Okay the additional info was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. The stuff I read about descriptive set theory was kind of a bit over my head so I just stopped reading :-)